# EF6 and pre-generated views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, t4

I am using EF code first method in my project. Recently I updated EF version of my project to `EF 6` using Package Manager Console.

All of my entities are inherited from a `BaseEntity` class as a super class :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }


    States _state;

    [NotMapped]
    public States State { get; set;}

    public enum States
    {
        Unchanged,
        Added,
        Modified,
        Deleted
    }
    ....  
}
```

And also I don't add the `BaseEntity` in my `DbContext`, the program run without any problem, but since I added pre-generated views to my project using [EF6 CodeFirst View Generation T4 Template for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18a7db90-6705-4d19-9dd1-0a6c23d0751f?SRC=VSIDE) , when I generate the views there is no problem, but when I run my project, I got following error:

> The current model no longer matches the model used to pre-generate the mapping views, as indicated by the ViewsForBaseEntitySets786b989cf4a349108a38357765a23070.MappingHashValue property. Pre-generated mapping views must be either regenerated using the current model or removed if mapping views generated at runtime should be used instead. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=318050 for more information on Entity Framework mapping views.

Does know anyone where is the problem? Or at least what is the way to find the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are hitting [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1258) bug. The title suggests it was fixed in EF 6.1.0 alpha - can you try this release and confirm? If you still see the error can you create a bug on https://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create? Be sure to attach your model - without the model it will be very hard to fix this bug. Another approach to take is to use a different project of mine - interactive EF view generation. You can find more details [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/) and [here](https://efinteractiveviews.codeplex.com/). The project is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFInteractiveViews). Finally, is your model really that big that you need to use pre-generated views? View generation has been greatly improved in EF6 (and more improvements are coming in 6.1) so I am curious if you really see a significant improvement in your application start up time when using pre-generated views.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, I tried EF 6.1.0 Alpha and it worked without error. yeah my application is big(about 500 entities) and before upgrading to EF6, I used EF4.1, and by using pre-generated views my program start-up time, was about half time of the case that I don't use it, but when I upgraded to EF6.1.0 alpha, start-up time of my project doesn't have any visible improvement.

Comment: I am glad the issue is fixed. Stay tuned for EF6.1 RTM.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I have this issue with EF6.1.2 with a dbcontext that uses some inheritance. Can i report this somewhere or do you have any knowledge of this?

Comment: I am not aware of any bug causing this in 6.1.2. Maybe your model just changed and you need to re-create your views?

Comment: We're experiencing this too in EF6.1.2. Only start yesterday evening, regenerating views produces exactly the same outcome as the existing version of them that is failing.

Comment: Yeah, so we've downgraded to 6.1.1  and the problem has gone away. We're using EF Power Tools Beta 4 to create our views and that could well be out of date with 6.1.2.....(https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Comment: AFAIR there was some work done around metadata which might have affected views pre-generated with PowerTools. I don't think PowerTools is being updated since most of the functionality was moved to the EF Designer. You should try running your app without views - there were major improvements in this area so for small to medium models you will not see the difference. Alternatively, you can also try https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18a7db90-6705-4d19-9dd1-0a6c23d0751f or https://efinteractiveviews.codeplex.com/

Comment: Cheers thanks for that, not using pre-generated view isn't an option for us. It's way too slow to start the application without them.

Comment: Same problem here with 6.1.3. We've downgraded to 6.1.1 to things back to work again.

Comment: @KimTranjan - if you re-created your views after moving to 6.1.3 and things still don't work file a bug on http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/. You will need to include a repro.